# Can I install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and Pro side-by-side?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to use the extra features of Enterprise. But some of my team is on Pro, I'd like to be able to check what features they have available before recommending best practises for the team.

A side-by-side installation of both variants would be perfect. Is it possible?

Comment: no, it is not possible. the question is, why would you want to? Enterprise has everything pro does and more....

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, that is helpful. The reason I would like to do it is explained in my question.

Comment: you don't need to worry about that though... if you are recommending best practices then you need to ensure you are using the same SKU as what you will be giving to the team. you cannot use something specific to the enterprise SKU and then tell the team to use it when the pro SKU does not have that feature...

Comment: @Ahmedilyas why are you answering this question in the comments section and not in the answers section?

Comment: perfectly valid question..... for example I work with several clients. one gave me a user that enables the usage of pro and the other client gave me a user for enterprise.....

Comment: My employer currently grants me a VS2019 Enterprise License but at home I only have a Community Edition License. Due to COVID, I have to work at home right now and I have unreliable internet so remote desktop is a pain...

Answer (score 3):

Actually you **cannot** have both Visual Studio **2015 Enterprise** and Visual Studio **2015 Pro** installed side-by-side on the same machine as this feature was introduced with Visual Studio **2017** where you can have any 2017 editions installed side-by-side with each other **and** any previous version of Visual Studio versions like 2015 (but again - only one edition of previous version of VS).

For example for single machine it is:

OK:     **2017 Com** + **2017 Pro** + **2017 Ent** + **2015 Pro**

OK:     **2017 Com** + **2017 Ent** + **2015 Ent**

NOT OK: **2015 Pro** + **2015 Ent**

NOT OK: **2017 Com** + **2015 Com** + **2015 Ent**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run different versions of Visual studio side by side. I have visual studio 2015 professional and enterprise edition running in the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just replying to make sure that others do not get turned away by the first visible answer/comment by @Ahmedilyas, that says it's not possible.

My scenario was different, I wanted to quickly use the extra 'Architecture' feature found in Enterprise, that I did not have in my VS 2017 Professional version.

To the point...**YES you can**. Just open the visual studio installer, and if you do have 2017, you should have an option readily available to install Enterprise version, and it will NOT overwrite your previous installation. You have a choice to add features, choose custom installation folders, etc...